# Sort text file after the 16th column with p-values in bash

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I have a tab delimited textfile with 18 column and more than 300000 rows. I have also a header line and I would sort the whole text file by the 16th column, which contains p-values. So I would like to sort it, having the lowest p-values above and also leaving the headline as it is.
I already have a code, it doesn't give me any error message, but it only shows the header line in the output file, and nothing else.

Here is my file:

```
filename    CHROM   ID  x11_CT  x12_CT  CT1 CT2 SampleSize  x21_CT  x21 x22_CT  x22 x11 x12 chIGSFA P_value GZD ZGSR
V1003   1   rs3131972   212 1   1068    14  541 856 0.791127541589649   13  0.0120147874306839  0.195933456561922   0.000924214417744917    0.70567673346914    0.400882778478405   0.00649170940375354 0.0361163844076152
V1003   1   rs3131962   170 1   1066    14  540 896 0.82962962962963    13  0.012037037037037   0.157407407407407   0.000925925925925926    0.40191966550969    0.526099523335894   0.00450617283950613 0.027281782875571
V1003   1   rs12562034  128 0   1068    14  541 940 0.868761552680222   14  0.0129390018484288  0.118299445471349   0   0.951515008754774   0.329333964471109   0.00612270697448755 0.041938142300103 
V1003   1   rs12131377  78  0   1060    14  537 982 0.914338919925512   14  0.0130353817504655  0.0726256983240224  0   0.555433052966582   0.456106209942983   0.0037868148101911  0.0321609387794883
```

Output should look like this:

```
filename    CHROM   ID  x11_CT  x12_CT  CT1 CT2 SampleSize  x21_CT  x21 x22_CT  x22 x11 x12 chIGSFA P_value GZD ZGSR
V1003   1   rs12562034  128 0   1068    14  541 940 0.868761552680222   14  0.0129390018484288  0.118299445471349   0   0.951515008754774   0.329333964471109   0.00612270697448755 0.041938142300103 
V1003   1   rs3131972   212 1   1068    14  541 856 0.791127541589649   13  0.0120147874306839  0.195933456561922   0.000924214417744917    0.70567673346914    0.400882778478405   0.00649170940375354 0.0361163844076152
V1003   1   rs12131377  78  0   1060    14  537 982 0.914338919925512   14  0.0130353817504655  0.0726256983240224  0   0.555433052966582   0.456106209942983   0.0037868148101911  0.0321609387794883
V1003   1   rs3131962   170 1   1066    14  540 896 0.82962962962963    13  0.012037037037037   0.157407407407407   0.000925925925925926    0.40191966550969    0.526099523335894   0.00450617283950613 0.027281782875571
```

Here is my code:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -g -rk 16,16"}' file.txt > file_out.txt
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file?

Comment: `it doesn't complete what I want` How do you know that? How does it differ from what you want? `sort the whole text file after the 16th column` You mean sort on columns 16, 17 and 18? `sort -k 16` would be enough.

Comment: It only shows the header line, and nothing else in the output file, and no I meant sort by column 16. Sorry

Comment: You're calling `sort` with a non-POSIX option (`-g`). Given that it's not producing output I'm guessing the `sort` you're calling doesn't support `-g` and so is failing BUT in  that case it should be producing an error message saying that. Is there an error message or are you redirecting stderr to /dev/null or something? What does `printf '2\n1\n' | sort -g` on  the command line do?

Comment: The ```printf '2\n1\n' | sort -g```produces 1 and 2. so no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `sort` doesn't have a `-g` option and so it's failing and not producing any output. Try this instead just using POSIX options:

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print | "sort -nrk 16,16"}' file
filename        CHROM   ID      x11_CT  x12_CT  CT1     CT2     SampleSize      x21_CT  x21     x22_CT  x22     x11     x12     chIGSFA P_value     GZD     ZGSR
V1003   1       rs3131962       170     1       1066    14      540     896     0.82962962962963        13      0.012037037037037       0.157407407407407   0.000925925925925926    0.40191966550969        0.526099523335894       0.00450617283950613     0.027281782875571
V1003   1       rs12131377      78      0       1060    14      537     982     0.914338919925512       14      0.0130353817504655      0.0726256983240224  0       0.555433052966582       0.456106209942983       0.0037868148101911      0.0321609387794883
V1003   1       rs3131972       212     1       1068    14      541     856     0.791127541589649       13      0.0120147874306839      0.195933456561922   0.000924214417744917    0.70567673346914        0.400882778478405       0.00649170940375354     0.0361163844076152
V1003   1       rs12562034      128     0       1068    14      541     940     0.868761552680222       14      0.0129390018484288      0.118299445471349   0       0.951515008754774       0.329333964471109       0.00612270697448755     0.041938142300103
```

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, I was trying the ```-g``` command on something different a few days ago, and it worked. I think the problem is, that, in my data there are scientific numbers (not in my example, that was my mistake). So the ```-n``` doesn't work here, or does it?

Comment: I don't know, I dont have any sample input/output to test it against (hint, hint). Update your question to show truly representative sample input output including those scientific values that you think are problematic and to show us if `sort -g` works for you or not outside of awk. Also tell us in your question which version of awk you're running (awk --version).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try next script:

```
#!/bin/bash
head -n 1 file.txt > file_out.txt
tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -k 16 >> file_out.txt
```

This definitely works, according to your output sample, when you convert the blanks into tabs, obviously.

Comment: I added a sample to my main post, I apologize not giving it from the beginning on.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
cat <(head -n 1 file.txt) <(tail -n +2 file.txt | sort -nk16,16) > file_out.txt
```

Comment: It says this error: ```/localscratch/SGE/node06/job_scripts/32495: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/localscratch/SGE/node06/job_scripts/32495: line 32: `cat <(head -n 1 file.txt) <(tail -n +2 file.txt) | sort -nk16,16) > file_out.txt```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Which is your `bash` version? Please run `bash --version`.

Comment: ```GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)```

Comment: Your command line above includes extra `)` after the `tail` command. Please copy & paste my command line correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk (for array sorting):

```
awk 'NR==1 { print;next } { map[$3][$16]=$0 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for(i in map) { for(j in map[i]) { print map[i][j] } } }' file
```

Explanation

```
awk 'NR==1 { 
              print;next                                   # Header record, print and skip to the next line
           } 
           { 
              map[$3][$16]=$0                              # None header line - create a two dimensional array indexed by ID (assuming that it is unique in the file) and by 16th field with the line as the value
           } 
       END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";         # Set the array sorting to index number ascending
             for(i in map) { 
                for(j in map[i]) { 
                   print map[i][j]                         # Loop through the array printing the values
                } 
             } 
            }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1; NR>1{print | "sort -k16n"}' file | column -t

filename  CHROM  ID          x11_CT  x12_CT  CT1   CT2  SampleSize  x21_CT  x21                x22_CT  x22                 x11                 x12                   chIGSFA            P_value            GZD                  ZGSR
V1003     1      rs12562034  128     0       1068  14   541         940     0.868761552680222  14      0.0129390018484288  0.118299445471349   0                     0.951515008754774  0.329333964471109  0.00612270697448755  0.041938142300103
V1003     1      rs3131972   212     1       1068  14   541         856     0.791127541589649  13      0.0120147874306839  0.195933456561922   0.000924214417744917  0.70567673346914   0.400882778478405  0.00649170940375354  0.0361163844076152
V1003     1      rs12131377  78      0       1060  14   537         982     0.914338919925512  14      0.0130353817504655  0.0726256983240224  0                     0.555433052966582  0.456106209942983  0.0037868148101911   0.0321609387794883
V1003     1      rs3131962   170     1       1066  14   540         896     0.82962962962963   13      0.012037037037037   0.157407407407407   0.000925925925925926  0.40191966550969   0.526099523335894  0.00450617283950613  0.027281782875571
```